# Python object analogous to R object

Tags: python, plotly-dash, py-shiny

I have a question for you all specially for the ones who work with both R and Python. I am making a switch back to Python from R and I have hit a roadblock.

Background: When one needs to prepare a dashboard in R shiny, the simplest approach is to do all the processing outside shiny and pack it in an R object and call it inside shiny.

Aim: I want to make a dashboard in python using dash.

Problem/guidance needed: Can I do something similar to what is done in R, like doing all the processing in python and then packing it up in an object and loading it to dash/plotly.

Comment: Unfortunately questions asking for recommendations for tools, libraries, or tutorials are explicitly off-topic for stack overflow. If you do some research, try some things, and provide a [mcve] then your question will be more likely to attract specific answers to your specific questions. As it stands, this question is better for a general discussion forum

Comment: For example, [Dash has extensive documentation and tutorials](https://dash.plotly.com/introduction) for the integration with python that describe he general cases you seem to be asking about